# How to create a slice with repeated elements

Tags: go

I need a (non-loopy) way to create a slice of `ints` with `n` repeated copies of an element (say `10`).
Something equivalent of `strings.Repeat("a", n)` but for `[]int`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just capture it in a simple function:

```
func repeatedSlice(value, n int) []int {
    arr := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        arr[i] = value
    }
    return arr
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://play.golang.org/p/6v74MOY7i64).